# An iframe that contains a photo slideshow breaks on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, widget

I have this weird problem and I can't seem to find what is wrong. Let me explain it step by step.

Here is the link to the slideshow that I developed: http://guusebump.com/view/lennie/weddings (PIN 1234). You click on Play and the slideshow will play with some music.

I've also developed a widget version for that slideshow, located at: http://guusebump.com/widget/lennie/weddings, which works fine as well.

Now, the problem is, I'm trying to plug that widget in another website using iframe:

```
<iframe width="900" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://guusebump.com/widget/lennie/weddings"></iframe>
```

But the slideshow wouldn't work on Chrome - it just won't work. Link: http://trisle.net/demoguuse/ (scroll down a bit to the widget). I tested the site on Safari and Firefox, it works for those browsers but not on Chrome. Not sure what will happen on your browsers, but I'm sure there's something wrong with the iframe.

What do you think? Any help would be much appreciated :)

**-UPDATE-**

The screen record of the error is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2ujp85y9fxxxz3/error_guuse.mov?dl=0

Comment: What is the problem with Chrome? On Chrome/Ubuntu, it seems to be working: slideshow changing images and music playing...

Comment: Hi @ValentinH, here's what happens on my Chrome/MacOSX https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2ujp85y9fxxxz3/error_guuse.mov?dl=0 :( Have you tried on a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to clear your browser cache.  I have this problem from time to time with Chrome for some reason.

Steps to clear browser cache:

1. Press CTRL + SHIFT + DEL KEYS while you are in the Chrome browser.
2. Make sure the cached image and files option is check marked. It usually is by default.
3. Press Clear browsing data button and wait for it to complete.
4. Exit the browser and try reloading your application to see what happens.

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for the response, but that doesn't fix it :( Here's what happens on my Chrome/MacOSX https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2ujp85y9fxxxz3/error_guuse.mov?dl=0

Comment: I Will Try And Take A Look At IT Tommorrow If U Havent Found A Solution

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) I still haven't found a solution.

Comment: I was looking at the source code of your website and I was wondering what the style="display:none" is used for in your iframe element?

Comment: Can you also tell me what version of chrome you are using?

Comment: Version is 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit) (up to date). BTW - can you be more specific about the display:none? Which element is that? And in what page?

Comment: It is on line 190 this is the markup:                                 <iframe style="display:none" id="sc-widget" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https://soundcloud.com/isolesty/sentimental-scenery-09-ashes" width="100%" height="100" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>    I found it by click on view source on the link you provided earlier http://guusebump.com/view/lennie/weddings

Comment: That iframe is for the SoundCloud widget, it plays the music so there's nothing wrong with it anyway.

Answer (score -2):

This might be the security issue with chrome. I am asking the user to disable that and check.

It is working fine in my machine. I have windows 7 with chrome. It might be some issues with your Mac OS.
It might be security issues.

Please disable the security settings in chrome using the below command and just try

```
chrome --disable-web-security
```

Comment: That still doesn't fix. The same issue happens... I just a support ticket to Chrome.

Comment: Could you please open the console window in chrome and check if any errors are coming while you click on play button?

Comment: Just so you are aware here is an error I get in the debugging console of chrome when the page first loads.  Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS  This error is linked to the following resource    https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/77475748